# scope of a variable

Tags: java, android, variables, scope

How can I get the value of a method parameter "myInteger" in this code.

```
public void myMethod(int myInteger) {
    View.OnClickListener myClearHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //***How can I get the value of "myInteger" here?***
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're just trying to *read* it, you just need to make it final:

```
public void myMethod(final int myInteger) {
    View.OnClickListener myClearHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int foo = myInteger;
        }
    };
}
```

In Java, only `final` parameters and local variables can be accessed within anonymous inner classes.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. What about assigning a value to it?

Comment: @Gohary: You can't assign do that in Java - the closure options are somewhat limited. You *can* use a wrapper type - e.g. an array - and change the contents of the wrapper within the inner class. Whether that's appropriate in your case is hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing the language should support closures and all you need to do in this case is use the variable `myInteger` in your `onClick` listener and you should be fine.. This works in fine in many languages I am not sure about Java though.

```
public void myMethod(final int myInteger) {
    View.OnClickListener myClearHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          int myInteger = myInteger * 100;
        }
    };
}
```

AS posted by John Skeet: the final keyword is important here.

Answer (score 1):

```
You Cannot refer to a non-final variable myInteger inside an inner class 
defined in a different method
```

You might be getting this error, so for that you have to declare it as final like this

```
final int myInteger
```